# What's the difference between useLazyQuery's then-callback and the onCompleted-callback?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

What's the difference between following 2 strategies? What strategy is better?

```js
  // using then callback of promise
  const [query, { loading }] = useLazyQuery(gqlQuery);

  const execQuery = (variables) => {
    query({ variables })
      .then(({ data }) => {
        //process data, set state, exec side effects
      });
  }
```

```js
  // using the onCompleted callback
  const [query, { loading }] = useLazyQuery(gqlQuery, {
    onCompleted({ data }) {
      //process data, set state, exec side effects
    }
  });

  const execQuery = (variables) => {
    query({ variables });
  }
```

It seems, that onCompleted returns faster in case of `cache-first`. Is that correct?

Comment: Neither will return faster, just depends where you want your logic to live. `onCompleted` and `onError` will let you declare behavior in the query definition, whereas you would need individual effects to do things based on `data`/`error`.

Comment: @bryce I don't think it's the same. What if the query is in cache? When I use the `then`-callback, it seems that I will never get the cached result immediately, but that's exactly what I want to achieve. Unfortunately there are bugs surrounding useLazyQuery (i.e. https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/9846), so in the moment it's difficult to investigate this. Maybe someone can give some hints.